# Call to a member function getId() on null

Tags: magento-1.9, products

I'm trying to create my first Magento module, and I have a strange error.
I have this method in my model (it extends `Mage_Core_Model_Abstract`) :

```
public function getAllProducts() { 
        $products = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection()->addAttributeToSelect('*')->setOrder('entity_id', 'DESC')->setPageSize(5);
        return $products;
    }
```

And I'm calling this method from a block:

```
public function getAllProducts() {

    $arrayOfProducts = array(); 
    $products = Mage::getModel('recentproducts/recentproducts')->getAllProducts();

    foreach ($products as $product) {
      var_dump($product);
      $arrayOfProducts[] = array('id' => $product­->getId(),'name' => $product­->getName(),'url' => $product­->getProductUrl());
    }

    return $arrayOfProducts;
  }
```

On my `phtml`, when doing this :

```
<?php
$products = $this->getAllProducts();
?>
```

I have `Fatal error: Call to a member function getId() on null in`...`

`getId()`is a product getter function, and when `var_dump($product)` I have all the product data printed . It's the same problem with `getName()` and all getter functions. What could be the problem ?

Answer (score 0):

Nothing is wrong with this particular snippet. Verify what file and line of code is mentioned in error message. Seems like the error occurs not in code part you mentioned.

Comment: it's on this line `$arrayOfProducts[] =... ` where the `getId() ` is.